# Trying to use cmake-mode in emacs, flycheck error

Tags: flycheck, rtags

I have some problem when I trie to use cmake-mode in emacs :

```
Syntax checker in buffer CMakeLists.txt in cmake-mode:

rtags
- major mode:    `cmake-mode' not supported
- may enable:    yes
- RTags enabled: enabled

Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled
checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32
Emacs version:    30.0.50
System:           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Window system:    x
```

and :

```
File mode specification error: (user-error Can’t use syntax checker rtags in this buffer)
```

Comment: What compiler do you use? (gcc/clang/other). With ```C-c ! ?``` try  to select your compiler instead of rtags.

Comment: you have `rtags` setup as a checker. `rtags` is not for CMake.